# OpenShift (Next Gen) and GitHub vs BitBucket

Tags: git, github, openshift, bitbucket

I would like to evaluate OpenShift (Next Gen). However at the very first step I faced an issue which prevents me to continue. In order to create an application from command line, the documentation says to execute the command:

> $ oc new-app /path/to/source/code

Quite simple, but it also specifies:

> If using a local Git repository, the repository must have an origin remote that points to a URL accessible by the OpenShift Online cluster.

Well, my local repository actually has an origin, which is a private Bitbucket repo, and I want to use it, not something else. Nonetheless when I created my OpenShift Online (Next Gen) Developer Preview account I had to link it to my GitHub account, therefore I assume that an "URL accessible by the OpenShift Online cluster" means a GitHub repo by default. Am I right? In that case, is there a way to switch to my BitBucket account or make a private BitBicket repo accessible to OpenShift Online cluster?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not restricted to using a Git repository hosted on GitHub. You can use any accessible Git hosting service, including GitLab and Bitbucket.

If you have a private repository though, you do need to provide to OpenShift the credentials so it can be accessed.

You find some documentation on how to set up credentials for private repositories at:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds.html#using-private-repositories-for-builds